# How to distinguish "lecturer" and "reader" in Latin?

Tags: word-comparison, academic-latin, vocabulary, occupation

Universities in the UK have two distinct titles (among others): "lecturer" and "reader".
A reader is more senior than a lecturer but both are below a professor.
The US (rough?) equivalents are "assistant professor" and "associate professor".

I would translate both of these words into Latin as *lector* or *lectrix*.
Perhaps I could translate "lecturer" as *lector/lectrix* and "reader" as *lector/lectrix senior*, but I wonder if there is a better way.
How do you suggest translating the two titles?
Do such translations already exist, canonical or not?

Comment: When did these distinctions arise? Was it with the first universities or later? Anyway, I guess if there is such a distinction, it is undoubtedly Medieval Latin. **update:** What if it has to do with the origin of degrees? Both _doctor_ and _magister_ are basicaly persons that teach.

Comment: @Rafael, I know nothing about the history of this distinction. That would be very relevant. I know of no similar distinction in continental Europe. Nowadays both positions require a doctor's degree, so it would be best not to refer to these positions by either *doctor* or *magister* (of any kind).

Comment: another difficulty may arise from the fact that _professor_ in Latin does not overlap exactly in meaning with the use they give to it in the UK.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this dictionary](https://books.google.fr/books?id=hOMTAAAAYAAJ) or [this one](https://books.google.fr/books?id=dM0GAQAAIAAJ), both are translated by ***prælector***.

Lewis&Short gives then this definition of *prælector*:

> praelector, ōris, m. id., one who reads an author to others and adds explanations, a prelector (post-class.; cf.: lector, recitator), Gell. 18, 5, 6.

[Cassel's dictionary](https://books.google.fr/books?id=Pz9aAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA383) proposes ***scholasticus*** as *a lecturer in the schools, teacher of rhetoric, rhetorician.*

And finally, [this dictionary](https://books.google.fr/books?id=qZtgAAAAcAAJ&pg=PT932) accepts *professor* for lecturer.

Comment: I don't think this answers the question, which explicitly asks how to *distinguish* these two positions in Latin.

Comment: *scholasticus/professor* seems to be more a *lecturer* than a *reader*.

Comment: Here in Cambridge a praelector is something totally different from a lecturer and from a reader. http://www.joh.cam.ac.uk/glossary/term/198

Comment: Indeed, my answer was only the result of search in dictionaries, so the question still awaits more precise answers…